# C# WinForms Button that Triggers Form Extension

Tags: c#, winforms

How would I go about creating a program that contains a button. This button does the following function:

> When clicked, it extends the Form size and adds what I want added onto the form.
>   The extended form can also resize itself back to normal.

Example here would be a gif of how Steam does so.

> https://gyazo.com/7330b65d05573208db0eb71a7587d21f

See how it does that addition here.

Extension in Picture --

[image]

Comment: You can add a panel in which you will add this text and set it's visible property to true when needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First design the form in its expanded view. Put everything that belongs to the red box (in your example) into a panel. Set all control's 'Anchor' properties below this box to "Bottom". Then you simply have to set the .Visible property of the panel to true or false, and at the same time, adjust the form's size. When you hide the panel and reduce the form's size, the controls below then panel will move up and close the gap.